# How to integrate Hubspot App with live CRM?

Tags: php, hubspot, hubspot-crm

I don't know if I'm missing something, but I've carefully followed Hubspot's API documentation and have successfully integrated my codebase with a "Test Hub", using cURL and PHP, but I cannot figure out how to now point this to the live hub? Where do I get the Client ID and Client Secret from my live Hubspot account? Or at least connect my live site to the app I have created?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so apparently you have to have a matching developer account email address as the one that is in the Hubspot account. That is, if you are a developer, you have to also have an account inside of the Hubspot instance you are connecting to.

Thanks BAD UI and documentation.